# Proper use of eraser tool above the image while drawing?

Tags: ios, iphone, drawing

I have one UIView in that I have draw image. On this View I am drawing pen tool, rectangle tool  and update the new image and draw. Just Like the [ACEDrawingView](https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEDrawingView)

I am facing one issue with the eraser tool. when I use the eraser the background image color is also gone. Please check the screenshot.

[image]

In the above image the black portion is pen drawing and white portion is my eraser drawing. what I want when user do the eraser drawing not to clear the background image. just the drawing.

**Redraw Image code**

```
    - (void)updateCacheImage:(BOOL)redraw
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    if (redraw) {
        // erase the previous image
        self.image = nil;

        // load previous image (if returning to screen)
        [[self.prev_image copy] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

        // I need to redraw all the lines
        for (id<ACEDrawingTool> tool in self.pathArray) {
            [tool draw];
        }

    } else {
        // set the draw point
        [self.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        [self.currentTool draw];
    }

    // store the image
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Eraser tool drawing

```
    - (void)draw
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextAddPath(context, self.path);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, self.lineAlpha);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `self.lineColor.CGColor` which i guess is the last chosen color, which is white in this case. Try replacing the current color with `[UIColor clearColor]` and add this line of code `CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this now ...Just found the solutions like following.Your eraser colour should be like your background view background colour.

example:
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, yourviewBackgroundColor);